# Is VBA programming similar in CATIA and Excel?

Tags: catia

I would like to create macro for specifc welding process in catia. So I need information that the VBA programming in catia is similar as excel or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

But, you must add the references for objects on Excel to be able to "see" them.

On the VBA editor on Excel, go to Tools -> References, and mark all the Catia Libraries you will need.

Also, to get the CATIA Application object reference on runtime you will need a function like this:

```
Function GetCatia() As INFITF.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Catia As INFITF.Application
    Set Catia = GetObject(, "Catia.Application")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Set GetCatia = Catia
    Else
        Set GetCatia = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```